# How to filter by attributes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 3 attributes: `:price, :type, :level` - so how can I filtering products by this attributes?

For example: I want search products with price below 20 dollars, type = sport, level = hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) `.where` method like so:

```
Product.where('price < ? AND type = ? AND level = ?', 20, "sport", "hard")
```